# Fetch data from many to many relationship with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 models, `store` and `dvd` with many to many relationship

`dvd` model:

```
    public function stores() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\store');
    }
```

`store` model:

```
    public function dvds ( ) {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\dvd');
    }
```

Then, in controller, when I need fetch data from both models, I use code like this:

```
    $res_store = store::orderBy("id","desc")->get();
    foreach( $res_store as $row ) {
        $dvds = $row->dvds()->get();
        foreach ($dvds as $dvd) {
            // echo columns here
        }            
    }
```

This works, but my question is, I'm doing this in correct way? I'm asking because it seems 2 loops  for this simple relation is somehow inefficient.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the right way.

When looping over a `$store`, you can access the associated `$dvd` records via `$store->dvds`; there is no need to call `$row->dvds()->get()`, as that is executing a new query with the same result of `$store->dvds`. Full code should simply be:

```
$stores = Store::with("dvds")->orderBy("id", "DESC")->get();
foreach($stores AS $store){
  foreach($store->dvds AS $dvd){
    ... // Do something with `$dvd`
  }
}
```

The `::with("dvds")` clause is known as "Eager loading", and prevents `$store->dvds` from needing execute another query behind the scenes.

Also, please name your models correctly. Classes in PHP are `StudlyCase`, so `Store` and `DVD`, not `store` and `dvd`.